# add or create 'Subject Alternative Name' field to self-signed certificate using makecert

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, self-signed, makecert

How can I create a certificate using `makecert` with a 'Subject Alternative Name' field ?

[image]

You can add *some* fields eg, 'Enhanced Key Usage' with the -eku option and I've tried the -san option but makecert doesn't like it.

This is a self-signed certificate so any method that uses IIS to create something to send off to a CA won't be appropriate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Makecert doesn't appear to support SANs so I created a certificate with SANs for use with IIS using OpenSSL. Check out my blog post about it:

> IIS 7 provides some easy to use wizards to create SSL certificates,
> however not very powerful ones. What I needed to do was to create SSL
> certificates that included a x.509 V3 extension, namely subject
> alternative names, a.k.a SANs. What SANs do is allow the website
> certificate to validate incoming requests by more than one URL domain
> name. This is really important when the web server is running web
> services such as WCF services and when other web services connect to
> them over SSL connections as with service oriented architectures.
> Unless special code is added to the web services to override the
> default SSL validation handler routines, the common name (CN) of the
> certificate MUST match the incoming request URL domain. So if the
> request was made using an FQDN, the certificate must have the FQDN as
> a CN or a SAN, a IP address or just a hostname will cause an SSL
> validation error and the connection will fail.
>
> SANs to the rescue… SANs support, among other things, DNS names and IP
> addresses. So by creating the certificate with SANs of the server FQDN
> and IP address, it increases the ways that other web services can
> connect.
>
> There are a number of tools that can generate certificates:
> makecert.exe, keytool.exe (java), selfssl.exe and openssl.exe. In
> addition, starting with Windows Vista and Server 2008 Microsoft added
> the CertEnroll API which can also create certificates programmatically
> either through COM interfaces.
>
> OpenSSL ended up doing exactly what I needed it to do. The process was
> fairly straight forward.
>
> 1. Construct an OpenSSL config file.
>
> [req] distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name x509_extensions =
> v3_req prompt = no [req_distinguished_name] C = US ST = VA L =
> Somewhere O = MyOrg OU = MyOU CN = MyServerName [v3_req] keyUsage =
> keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
> subjectAltName = @alt_names [alt_names] DNS.1 = MyServerName DNS.2 =
> 10.0.1.34 IP.1 = 10.0.1.34 IP.2 = 192.167.20.1
>
> 2. Create x509 request with OpenSSL
>
> openssl.exe req -x509 -nodes -days 730 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout
> C:\cert.pem -out C:\cert.pem -config C:\PathToConfigFileAbove.txt
>
> 3. Create a PFX containing the keypair
>
> openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -out C:\cert.pfx -in C:\cert.pem -name "My
> Cert" -passout pass:mypassword
>
> 4. Import the PFX into IIS using the import link in the server
>    certificates area.
> 5. Bind the certificate to the IIS websites.
>
> And viola, we know have a SSL certificate for IIS with SANs so we can
> connect using multiple domain names without certificate validation
> errors.

Source: [*Creating certificates with SANs using OpenSSL*](http://andyarismendi.blogspot.com/2011/09/creating-certificates-with-sans-using.html) by Andy Arismeti, Thursday, September 1, 2011

Answer (score 35):

An even easier way is to use the New-SelfSignedCertificate PowerShell commandlet, which includes a SAN by default. In a single command you can create the certificate and add it to the store.

`New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName localhost -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My`

Note that you need to run PowerShell as an administrator.

Comment: how do you pass the subject alternative name(s) to that commandlet?

Comment: It creates one for you based on the DnsName provided.  You can also pass in a comma delimited list if you need to support multiple URLs.  E.g. `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName localhost, mysite.com, test.com -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My`

Comment: Even if you install Powershell v4, this command is ONLY available on Windows Server 2012+ and Windows 8+ (or maybe 8.1+ ??)  No Win 7 and no Server 2008 :(

Comment: @Jester Considering that this is a self-signed certificate, I think that needing to install it on a server kinda tells you that you should consider grabbing a certificate from, say Let’s Encrypt.

Comment: How to issue a certificate using my own TestCA through `New-SelfSignedCertificate`?

Comment: I was recently trying to do this again for Win7: just use a Win 2012 machine, create cert, then export and import to the Win7 box and it works fine.

Comment: Relevant: [How to create self-signed SAN certificate in IIS?](https://serverfault.com/a/892209/145950)

Answer (score 11):

**Update**

The certificate generated using the below `makecert` method does not work reliably in all browsers, because it does not actually generate a "Subject Alternative Name".

If you examine the certificate you will see that it does not actually have a `Subject Alternative Name` field, but instead specifies multiple `CN` in the `Subject` field.

E.g.

```
Subject:
CN = blah.foo.corp
CN = blah
```

Whereas a real "SAN" cert would have something like:

```
Subject Alternative Name:
DNS Name=blah.foo.corp
DNS Name=blah
```

To understand the differences and history between the "Subject" field with "Common Name" and the "Subject Alternative Name" field, I recommend reading [The (soon to be) not-so Common Name](http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=381).

So it appears that `makecert` *cannot* be used to generate a true "SAN" cert, and you will need to use other tools, such as `openssl`.

---

**Original Answer:**

At least with the version of `makecert` that comes with Visual Studio 2012, you can specify multiple subjects, simply by specifying a comma separated list `-n "CN=domain1, CN=domain2"`

E.g. (from the technet blog [Makecert.exe SAN and Wildcard certificate](http://blogs.technet.com/b/uday/archive/2012/06/21/makecert-exe-san-and-wildcard-certificate.aspx))

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=*.fabrikam.com, CN=*.contoso.com" -b 01/01/2010 -e 01/01/2100 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -len 2048
```

Comment: To be clear, you don't want to use multiple SubjectCNs, as Firefox only respects the last and Chrome only respects the first.