# Is there a standard URL for a web service?

Tags: web-services, url

I need a certificate for my (WCF) web services.  My company's web site (www.company.com) may or may not be the location for the web service, so I don't want to use the www URL when I create my SSL cert and build my web clients.  Is there a prefix that is commonly used for web services (e.g. service.company.com)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such prefix, but you can get a wildcard certificate that is valid for *.company.com.  Then you can decide later.

Comment: How does that work?  I'm pretty sure that WCF (and IIS) will issue a warning if the host name doesn't match the common name on the SSL certificate.

Comment: See e.g. this wikipedia article as a starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate

Comment: This looks promising.  Found this note about using it specifically with WCF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385815/wcf-over-https-using-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate.

Comment: Apparently you don't get something for nothing.  The wildcard certificate is significantly more expensive than the single site.