# Call API on server that is signed using Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp, self-signed-certificate

I'm working on an `Android` application that call some `API`s over `https`. using `retrofit2` and `okhttp3`. During my development I use a self-signed certificate that I generate in server. I face a lot of problems in calling `API`s as I'm using a self-signed certificate, I solve them all but stuck on this exception `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`.

Currently I had copy my certificate `ServerCertificate.cer` to `Download` directory in order to load it and add it to allowed `KeyStore`.
I try a lot of solutions from different websites. I try `okhttp` [CustomTrust](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java) and from [Android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#UnknownCa) website

I write below code depending on Android developer example:

```java
X509TrustManager mTrustManager = null;

private Retrofit getRetrofit(String identity, String serverBaseUrl) {
        Retrofit retrofit = null;

        try {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(getSSLConfig().getSocketFactory(), mTrustManager)
                    .addInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor(identity))
                    .addInterceptor((new okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor())
.setLevel(okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(serverBaseUrl)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        return retrofit;
    }

private SSLContext getSSLConfig() throws Exception {
        FileHelper fileHelper = FileHelper.getInstance();
        String cerFilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/ServerCertificate.cer";


        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = new FileInputStream(cerFilePath);
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            //Below line print: ca=CN=SS_CEM_5_4
            System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        mTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];

        return context;
    }
```

Currently when I call any `API` I get following exception:

```
 Exception occurred while calling heartbeat
    javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname ss_cem_5_4 not verified:
        certificate: sha256/OUxkHCacC0q0+ZQpL/3V1jFgV57CXweub/lSSUXsAZw=
        DN: CN=\00S\00S\00_\00C\00E\00M\00_\005\00_\004
        subjectAltNames: []
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:330)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:283)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:168)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at co.sedco.sevicesbase.managementproxy.webproxy.CustomInterceptor.intercept(CustomInterceptor.java:39)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:186)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:92)
        at co.sedco.sevicesbase.managementproxy.webproxy.ManagementWebProxy.callHeartbeat(ManagementWebProxy.java:271)
        at co.sedco.sevicesbase.heartbeat.HeartbeatManager$CallHeartbeatTimerTask.run(HeartbeatManager.java:91)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

I only managed to make self-signed certificate work by adding `HostnameVerifier` to `OkHttpClient` and override `Verify` function to always return `true`, but this solution is not acceptable, I believe that I will encounter a situations where I have to use a self-signed certificate in customer server (Although it is not recommended).

I'm calling Server using Url: `https://ss_cem_5_4/Portal/api/GetHeartbeat`

I also should mention that I was unable to call server through server name so I modified `hosts` file in path '/system/etc/' to add mapping for my server. (I'm working on a rooted device)

Comment: As you followup in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767266/openssl-certificate-chain-cn-is-corrupted the problem is indeed surely in the `\00` in the certificate. Also `subjectAltNames` is empty, which is not good, it should be filled.

Comment: Thank you for your help, yes it seems the problem that `subjectAltNames` was empty, after filling it code worked successfully.
I was generating certificate using `IIS` and it seems that it does not fill `subjectAltNames` it only fill `CN`, so I generate certificate using `PowerShell` `New-SelfSignedCertificate` and it work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours searching for a solution for the problem finally it has been solved. I will write here my solution in case anyone face same problem.

First there was a problem in `Self-Signed certificate`, as Patrick Mevzek mention in the comments `subjectAltNames` was empty, and after checking how `OkHostnameVerifier` verify the server you are calling is trusted or not, it check `subjectAltNames` that server name in the `Url` match any name in certificate `subjectAltNames`.

Previously I was generating my self-signed certificate using `IIS` and it appear that it only fill certificate Common Name `CN` and keep `subjectAltNames` empty. I had a hint regarding this problem from following stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17225029/4496429). In order to solve this problem I generate a new license by running below command on server `PowerShell`.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "ss_cem_5_4" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

Please make sure to run `PowerShell` as administrator, and for more information regarding `New-SelfSignedCertificate` command parameters you can check this [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps).

My second problem (or requirement) was to trust my self-signed certificate, I try some solutions but they all led to only trust my certificate, I was unable to call websites which have a certificate that is trusted by `Android` by default, so I search for a solution to extend `Android` trusted certificates, and with the help of this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378872/4496429) I manage to accomplish that, and below is my full code.

Below class is used to extend `Android` trusted certificates:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    protected SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public TrustManager[] TrustManager;

    public AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore keyStore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        //super(null, null, null, null, null, null);
        super();
        TrustManager = new TrustManager[]{new AdditionalKeyStoresTrustManager(keyStore)};
        sslContext.init(null, TrustManager, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    /**
     * Based on http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509TrustManager
     */
    public static class AdditionalKeyStoresTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        protected ArrayList<X509TrustManager> x509TrustManagers = new ArrayList<X509TrustManager>();


        protected AdditionalKeyStoresTrustManager(KeyStore... additionalkeyStores) {
            final ArrayList<TrustManagerFactory> factories = new ArrayList<TrustManagerFactory>();

            try {
                // The default Trustmanager with default keystore
                final TrustManagerFactory original = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                original.init((KeyStore) null);
                factories.add(original);

                for (KeyStore keyStore : additionalkeyStores) {
                    final TrustManagerFactory additionalCerts = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                    additionalCerts.init(keyStore);
                    factories.add(additionalCerts);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }



            /*
             * Iterate over the returned trustmanagers, and hold on
             * to any that are X509TrustManagers
             */
            for (TrustManagerFactory tmf : factories)
                for (TrustManager tm : tmf.getTrustManagers())
                    if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager)
                        x509TrustManagers.add((X509TrustManager) tm);


            if (x509TrustManagers.size() == 0)
                throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find any X509TrustManagers");

        }

        /*
         * Delegate to the default trust manager.
         */
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            final X509TrustManager defaultX509TrustManager = x509TrustManagers.get(0);
            defaultX509TrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
        }

        /*
         * Loop over the trustmanagers until we find one that accepts our server
         */
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            for (X509TrustManager tm : x509TrustManagers) {
                try {
                    tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
                    return;
                } catch (CertificateException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
            throw new CertificateException();
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            final ArrayList<X509Certificate> list = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
            for (X509TrustManager tm : x509TrustManagers)
                list.addAll(Arrays.asList(tm.getAcceptedIssuers()));
            return list.toArray(new X509Certificate[list.size()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Below code is to create my `AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory`

```java
private Certificate getCertificate(String cerFilePath) throws Exception {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        InputStream caInput = new FileInputStream(cerFilePath);
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        return ca;
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory getSSLConfig() throws Exception {
        FileHelper fileHelper = FileHelper.getInstance();
        String downloadPath = fileHelper.getDeviceDownloadPath() + File.separator;
        String[] cerFilePath = new String[]{downloadPath + "ServerCertificate.cer", downloadPath + "ServerCertificate2.cer", downloadPath + "ServerCertificate3.cer", downloadPath + "ServerCertificate4.cer"};

        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < cerFilePath.length; i++) {
            Certificate ca = getCertificate(cerFilePath[i]);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca" + i, ca);
        }

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        mTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
        AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory factory = new AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory(keyStore);

        return factory;
    }
```

and adding my custom `SSLSocketFactory` using below code:

```java
SSLSocketFactory factory = getSSLConfig();
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(factory, (X509TrustManager) ((AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory) factory).TrustManager[0])
                    .build();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(serverBaseUrl)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

Disclaimer: I copy my certificates to the download directory, I do not think this is a good idea because it has a lot of security risks, my code is just for demonstration