# openssl certificate chain CN is corrupted

Tags: ssl, openssl, self-signed-certificate

I'm working on Android application that call some web services from my server. I have created a `Self-Signed Certificate` from `IIS` to test calling `API`s over `https` but failed with `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` exception.

I already ask a question on stackoverflow regarding this [Call API on server that is signed using Self-Signed Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760354/call-api-on-server-that-is-signed-using-self-signed-certificate)

After some digging and searching how to solve issue, I try the solution from following stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378872/4496429)

When I try to read server certificate information using `openssl` I get following Certificate chain:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=\x00S\x00S\x00_\x00C\x00E\x00M\x00_\x005\x00_\x004
   i:/CN=\x00S\x00S\x00_\x00C\x00E\x00M\x00_\x005\x00_\x004
```

My server name is `SS_CEM_5_4`, and above exception indicate that verifying host name failed.

Are these `\x00` characters before each CN character is the problem, which lead to mismatch between certificate host name and server name?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Where should I start looking for the solution, generating certificate or my application?

Note: I create a new thread for this question to focus on certificate rather than my `Android` application.

Comment: "Are these \x00 characters before each CN character is the problem", yes they should not be there. It looks like some encoding error, like UTF-16 or something. How was the certificate generated in the first place? You do not say...

Comment: I generate certificate using `IIS` after generating it using `PowerShell New-SelfSignedCertificate` it worked successfully. For anyone who is facing same problem I will answer my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57760354/4496429) with details.